# How to update a 'Sort Index' column of a list of records with one call

Tags: mysql

Basically, I have a list of records in a mysql db.  These records are ordered 1 to 10.  The user can re-order these records to whatever order they want.  They will press a button to update all the records to their newly, respective order number.  For example:

```
ID | Sort_Index | Name
----------------------
1  |     1      | Jim
2  |     2      | Bob
3  |     3      | Carl
4  |     4      | Bill
5  |     5      | Wendy
```

The user can change these to this for example:
Note: the changed values are stored into an array before I make the UPDATE calls

```
ID | Sort_Index | Name
----------------------
1  |     1      | Carl
2  |     2      | Wendy
3  |     3      | Bob
4  |     4      | Jim
5  |     5      | Bill
```

My question is, how can I make this mysql call with one call, using the new values in my array, instead of one call for each record?

If this is impossible or simply the "wrong way to do it", please feel free to suggest new ideas as I am not fully committed to this idea as of now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a limited number of rows, you could implement this with an sql CASE statement --

```
Update users set sort_index = case id when 1 then <newval> when 2 then <newval>...
```

Comment: that is it.  I knew there had to be a simple method to it.  thank you mark.